# setting rewrite rules in httpd.config file at host server

Tags: htaccess, php, httpd.conf

I am a new webmaster. I plan to host my website on a dedicated server. The website has three TLD: `.com`, `.ma` and `.fr`.

I have a couple of rewrite directives in my `.htaccess` file that force the URL format to `http://example.com` with this code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)(.+) [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.+)
RewriteRule ^ http://%2%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Plus other rules. I want to place some of these rules, especially the URL format in the `httpd.conf` file but I don't know what to write in `ServerName` and `ServerAlias` as I have three ServerNames: `example.com`, `example.ma` and `example.fr`. Plus if a user omit `www` or add it then it's a new ServerName. How can I set these rules in `httpd.conf` and under what ServerName?

Comment: Presumably, you don't currently have a working site with 3 different domains? (Or is it currently hidden from view on a _shared_ server?) "format to `http://example.com`" - strictly speaking, that code just removes the `www` subdomain (if present) on whatever domain is requested (but I expect you know that), it doesn't redirect to `http://example.com` as you seem to imply in your description. Do these 3 domains serve exactly the same content, or is there some customisation (ie. localisation) for each domain?

Comment: @MrWhite, i don't have a working website yet, the code doesn't remove the www, it redirects to the website without https and www because i use the flag R=301 which means redirect with code 301, and i serve same content without any customisation for each domain

Comment: I always recommend using the .Htaccess file for common rewrite and blocking. The reason is simple. If the rules are within your httpd.conf file and there is an error, Apache will not start effecting all of the sites negatively. However, if you use .Htaccess and make a mistake, only one site is effected. In principle, you should set up your Apache configuration files once and leave them alone as much as possible. Save the editing for less risky areas. Cheers!!

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was that your description seems to imply that you are canonicalising the hostname (to `example.com`), but it really just removes the www subdomain on whatever domain is accessed (and yes, removes HTTPS also).  (_Aside:_ But why are you trying to redirect from HTTPS to HTTP?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to clarify usage... you can only have one `ServerName` directive. If you have more than one then the later directive simply overrides the earlier one. However, you can have many `ServerAlias` directives. In terms of resolving the requested domain name (ie. you request `www.example.ma` and the server is able to match this) it doesn't really matter whether `www.example.ma` is defined as the `ServerName` or a `ServerAlias` - the server will find it just the same.

The `ServerName` doesn't just define the hostname, it can also define the scheme and port number. Whereas, `ServerAlias` defines only a hostname. Since, in your case, all these domains appear to be using the same scheme and port, it doesn't really matter. (If you had different schemes and ports then you'd be defining separate VitualHosts anyway and each would have its own `ServerName` - you could still do this.)

The value supplied to `ServerName` can also be used to construct self-referential redirection URLs. However, this is not the default behaviour (you would need to explicitly set `UseCanonicalName On`). And if you have multiple domains, then you probably just want to leave it as the default. The default being that it will use the hostname from the request (ie. `HTTP_HOST`).

*Aside:* I assume these three domains all point to the same area of the filesystem, run the same scripts and share log files? A single server config or VirtualHost. Otherwise, you might consider separate VirtualHosts for each domain.

So, having said all that, it probably doesn't really matter which domain you set as the `ServerName` and which domains you set as `ServerAlias`. However, you must choose one host as the `ServerName`. To me, the logical one would be `example.com` (the gTLD and no-www). The ccTLD domains, together with the www variants would be defined as `ServerAlias`.

For example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com
ServerAlias example.ma www.example.ma
ServerAlias example.fr www.example.fr
UseCanonicalName Off
:
```

Your mod_rewrite redirect would work unchanged in either the VirtualHost or `.htaccess` context.

---

However, slight digression...

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on 
> :
> RewriteRule ^ http://%2%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
> ```

...why are you redirecting from HTTPS to HTTP?! If anything it should be the other way round. There is no good reason to be redirecting from HTTPS to HTTP in 2017. In order for this to even "work" the SSL certs must be installed anyway!

---

**UPDATE:**

> i want to redirect to only one domain so it won't be considered duplicate by SEO

However, if you do want to canonicalise the domain name and redirect everything to `example.com` instead then you would do this slightly differently to the above. Your current mod_rewrite code does not do this.

Instead, you would define two `<VirtualHost>` containers, one for your canonical 
domain and one for all the others. Then use a simple mod_alias `Redirect` to your canonical domain (not mod_rewrite).

For example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.example.com
ServerAlias example.ma www.example.ma
ServerAlias example.fr www.example.fr

# Redirect everything to the canonical domain
Redirect / http://example.com/
:

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.com
UseCanonicalName On
:
```

Comment: Thank you @MrWhite for your detailed answer, i really appreciate it, your code of VirtualHost with different ServerAlias answered my question, however you said that you thought i wanted to canonicalise the hostname, and asked about why i would redirect to https, it is because of SEO, because the 3 domains point to the same content, i want to redirect to only one domain so it won't be considered duplicate by SEO, my website doesn't support ssl, so if someone types https://example.com i want them to be redirect to the default domain without http, am i doing it the right way?

Comment: "asked about why i would redirect to https" - I asked about why you would redirect to HTTP (not HTTPS). If your "website doesn't support ssl" then you won't be able to redirect to HTTP anyway since users will get a browser error _before_ reaching your application code. "i want to redirect to only one domain so it won't be considered duplicate by SEO" - ok, but that's not what your code is currently doing. If you are canonicalising the domain name (redirecting everything to `example.com`) then you would probably construct your VirtualHosts / redirect differently to the above.

Comment: I've updated my answer with respect to canonicalizing the domain (as you mentioned in the above comment).

Comment: Thank you @MrWhite for your reply it answered my question perfectly, i don't mean to be annoying but what the UseCanonicalName directive is for?

Comment: If you have `UseCanonicalName On` (not the default) then the `SERVER_NAME` server variable refers to the value of the `ServerName` directive. Apache uses `SERVER_NAME` to construct absolute URLs (when it needs to). However, by default `SERVER_NAME` is the same as `HTTP_HOST`, which refers to whatever _host_ the user has specified in the request.

Comment: but the HTTP_HOST won't point to our server unless it matches the serverName specified in the virtualHost entries, how can the user enters whatever in the request yet still be redirected to our server?

Comment: The user will reach your server if the Host matches the ServerName or any of the ServerAlias directives. So, yes, in the second example, the `UseCanoncialName On` is mostly academic, since there is only a ServerName directive.